# Crystal Report Object not refreshing after IsPostBack

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, ispostback

This is my .Net 2 ASP.Net code that used to work when hosted on Win 2000 and IIS3.

'In Page_Load, if it's NOT a PostBack then remove the cached report object so the that code later is forced to rebuild it.

Under Win2000 and IIS3 when I clicked a link to load the Page fresh, in Page_Load it would call Session.Remove("ReportObject"), then in FillRptParams realise the Session("ReportObject") is Nothing and reload it.

I initially put all the Session code in to make sure that between Crystal Report page requests it wouldn't keep going to the DB, it would just pull the ReportObject from the session variable display the next page.

Now I've switched to Win 2003 and IIS6 I ALWAYS get the SAME report served up, even when clicking on the link as I used to which essentially causes IsPostBack to be false and remove the Session object.

I'm hoping it might some settings under IIS6 that can make it behave as it used to.

```
     Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

     If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
       Session.Remove("ReportObject")
     End If

     End Sub

     Sub FillRptParams(ByVal snavcode As String, Optional ByVal CrystalOrPDForEXCEL As String = "")

     If Not Session("ReportObject") Is Nothing Then
         bReportCached = True
     Else            
        bReportCached = False
     End If

     oSqlCmd = New SqlCommand

     If bReportCached Then
         orpt = Session("ReportObject")

     Else
           orpt = New rptUsageSummaryNew
           oSqlCmd.CommandText = "HOSP_RPT_UsageAllSummary"

           oDS = oDataAccess.GetReportDataSet(Session("Group"), oSqlCmd)
           orpt.SetDataSource(oDS)

           'Cache the report object so we don't have to load it again next time
           Session.Remove("ReportObject")
           Session.Add("ReportObject", orpt)
     End If

     End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your code in the Page_init event, not in the page_load.
And suppress your "if postback code" when you have moved it .

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Page_Init is firing on every run of the page and removing the Session object.  I need it detect a PostBack when the Crystal Report page navigation control is clicked and leave the Session object in tact.

Comment: Why do you need to recreate your report object ?  CR is designed to be created one time, and then cached to navigate between the page